# tikz node online is not aligned with text nearby

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does text made by `tikz` node not align with other text on the same line? That is to say, they are not on the same baseline.
And how to solve this?

Hereafter is the example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
aa\tikz \node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=1]at (0,0){|by tikz|};aa
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are many related questions, just google `tikz baseline text` or `tikz inline baseline` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416226. In addition the manual is full of `baseline` examples, e. g. `$A \mathbin{\tikz[baseline] \draw[-»] (0pt,.5ex) -- (3ex,.5ex);} B$
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. First, you need to load the `tikz`-package. Second, do not use the backslash for opening and closing the `node`-options. And, finally, you can use the `baseline`-key to achieve the desired effect.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
aa\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]\node[inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0){|by tikz|};aa
\end{document}
```